# Collision detection between rectangles libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision-detection

In my top down game how can I make my player collide when he pass through the baby crib? 
I'm using intersectRectangles .

Here is my code

```
Rectangle player = new Rectangle();
Rectangle babycrib = new Rectangle();
Rectangle intersection = new Rectangle(); 


// Load the sprite sheet as a texture
    cat = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("spriteCatsheet.png"));
    catsprite = new Sprite(cat);
    player = new Rectangle();
    player.x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - player.width - 350; 

    baby = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("baby.png"));
    sprite_baby = new Sprite(baby);
    babycrib = new Rectangle();
    sprite_baby.setPosition(180,4000);
```

Update Method

```
   public void update(){
    deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    camera.update();   
}
```

In render method

```
// check collision
    Intersector.intersectRectangles(player, babycrib, intersection);
     if(intersection.x > player.x)
        //Intersects with right side
     if(intersection.y > player.y)
            //Intersects with top side
     if(intersection.x + intersection.width < player.x + player.width)
                //Intersects with left side
     if(intersection.y + intersection.height < player.y + player.height)
                    //Intersects with bottom side
     Intersector.overlaps(player,babycrib);
```

Here is the full code

```
 public class GameScreen implements Screen ,InputProcessor {

final MyGdxGame game;
// Constant rows and columns of the sprite sheet
private static final int FRAME_COLS = 8, FRAME_ROWS = 4;
private boolean peripheralAvailable;
// Objects used
Animation<TextureRegion> walkAnimation; // Must declare frame type (TextureRegion)
Texture left_paw,right_paw;

Texture baby,cat;
SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
Sprite catsprite,sprite_baby;
ImageButton moveBackward,moveForward;
Viewport viewport;
private Stage stage;
private static float fade;
// A variable for tracking elapsed time for the animation
float stateTime;
private TextureRegion myTextureRegion;
TextureRegion textureRegion;
private TextureRegionDrawable myTexRegionDrawable;

OrthographicCamera camera;
Rectangle player = new Rectangle();
Rectangle babycrib = new Rectangle();
Rectangle intersection = new Rectangle();


float deltaTime;
int progressKnobX = 18;
Float fadeTime = 1f;

public GameScreen(final MyGdxGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport( 720, 1280));
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1280 ,720);
    Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
    camera.update();
    Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(true);
    Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 720, 1280);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor( this);
    peripheralAvailable = Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Accelerometer);
    viewport = new ScreenViewport();

    baby = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("equip/baby.png"));
    sprite_baby = new Sprite(baby);
    babycrib = new Rectangle();
    sprite_baby.setPosition(180,4000);


    // Load the sprite sheet as a texture
    cat = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("spriteCatsheet.png"));
    catsprite = new Sprite(cat);
    player = new Rectangle();
    player.x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - player.width - 350; //250;  //550 // 410
    // Use the split utility method to create a 2D array of TextureRegions. This is
    // possible because this sprite sheet contains frames of equal size and they are
    // all aligned.
    TextureRegion[][] tmp = TextureRegion.split(cat, cat.getWidth() /   FRAME_COLS , cat.getHeight()/ FRAME_ROWS);
    // Place the regions into a 1D array in the correct order, starting from the top
    // left, going across first. The Animation constructor requires a 1D array.
    TextureRegion[] walkFrames = new TextureRegion[FRAME_COLS * FRAME_ROWS];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < FRAME_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < FRAME_COLS; j++) {
            walkFrames[index++] = tmp[i][j];
        }
    }
    // Initialize the Animation with the frame interval and array of frames
    walkAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.099f, walkFrames);
    // Instantiate a SpriteBatch for drawing and reset the elapsed animation
    // time to 0
    spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch();
    stateTime = 0f;
    //left_control
    left_paw = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("left_paw.png"));
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(left_paw);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    moveBackward = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    moveBackward.getStyle().imageUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("left_paw.png"))));
    //the hover
    moveBackward.getStyle().imageDown = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("left_paw_hover.png"))));
    moveBackward.setPosition(10,25);
    stage.addActor(moveBackward); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    moveBackward.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("Left Button Pressed");
            //Start Animation
            progressKnobX = progressKnobX - 4;
            Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(true);
            motionState=MotionState.NONE;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.print("Released");
            Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
            motionState=MotionState.DOWN;
            return true;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(moveBackward);
    //right_control
    right_paw = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("right_paw.png"));
    myTextureRegion = new TextureRegion(right_paw);
    myTexRegionDrawable = new TextureRegionDrawable(myTextureRegion);
    moveForward = new ImageButton(myTexRegionDrawable); //Set the button up
    moveForward.getStyle().imageUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("right_paw.png"))));
    //the hover
    moveForward.getStyle().imageDown = new TextureRegionDrawable(new TextureRegion(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("right_paw-hover.png"))));
    moveForward.setPosition(517,25);
    stage.addActor(moveForward); //Add the button to the stage to perform rendering and take input.
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    moveForward.addListener(new InputListener(){
        @Override
        public void touchUp (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            System.out.println("Right Button Pressed");
            progressKnobX = progressKnobX + 4;

            motionState=MotionState.NONE;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean touchDown (InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            motionState=MotionState.UP;
            return true;
        }
    });
    stage.addActor(moveForward);
}
public enum State
{
    PAUSE,
    RUN,
    RESUME,
    STOPPED
}
private State state = State.RUN;

MotionState motionState=MotionState.NONE;
enum MotionState {
    NONE {
        @Override
        public boolean update(Rectangle player) {
            return true;
        }
    },

    UP {
        @Override
        public boolean update(Rectangle player) {
            player.y += 300 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            return false;
        }
    },
    DOWN{
        @Override
        public boolean update(Rectangle player) {
            player.y -= 300 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            return false;
        }
    },
    LEFT{
        @Override
        public boolean update(Rectangle player)  {
            player.x -= 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            return false;
        }
    },
    RIGHT{
        @Override
        public boolean update(Rectangle player) {
            player.x  += 100 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
            return false;
        }
    };
    public abstract boolean update(Rectangle player);
}

@Override
public void show() {
}
public void update(){
deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
camera.position.x += 10;
camera.position.y += 10;
camera.update();
}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    // clear previous frame
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.294f, 0.294f, 0.294f, 1f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear screen
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime(); // Accumulate elapsed animation time
    camera.update();
    update();
    spriteBatch.begin();
    stateTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    TextureRegion currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
    camera.position.x = player.getX() + 100; //190
    camera.position.y = player.getY() + 180;
    camera.position.x = 350;
    update();
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    spriteBatch.draw(currentFrame,player.x, player.y);
    sprite_baby.draw(spriteBatch);


    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) motionState = MotionState.DOWN;
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) motionState=MotionState.UP;
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) motionState=MotionState.LEFT;
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) motionState=MotionState.RIGHT;

    if(motionState.update(player)) motionState=MotionState.NONE;


    // check collision
    Intersector.intersectRectangles(player, babycrib, intersection);
    if(intersection.x > player.x)
        //Intersects with right side
        if(intersection.y > player.y)
            //Intersects with top side
            if(intersection.x + intersection.width < player.x + player.width)
                //Intersects with left side
                if(intersection.y + intersection.height < player.y + player.height)
                    //Intersects with bottom side
                    Intersector.overlaps(player,babycrib);
    //Intersects with bottom side


    if(!player.overlaps(babycrib)){
        Gdx.app.log("babycrib overlaps", "yes");
    }

    //Mobile acceleration
    if (Gdx.input.isPeripheralAvailable(Input.Peripheral.Accelerometer)) {
        player.x -= Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX();
    }
    if (player.x < 0) {
        player.x = 0;
        player.x += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() *20 *delta;
    }
    if (player.x > Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-player.getWidth() -150) {
        player.x = Gdx.graphics.getWidth()-player.getWidth() -150;
    }
    if(this.state==State.RESUME) {
        switch (state) {
            case RUN:
                //do suff here
                break;
            case PAUSE:
                break;
            case RESUME:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    spriteBatch.end();
    stage.act(); //acting a stage to calculate positions of actors etc
    stage.draw(); //drawing it to render all
}


@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
    camera.update();
}
@Override
public void pause() {

}
@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
    return false;
}
@Override
public void hide() {
}
@Override
public void dispose() { // SpriteBatches and Textures must always be disposed
}
}
```

Can anyone till me what is the correct implementation of rectangle collision detection there's no overlap happen , I'm new to this framework. Thank's and advance :)

Comment: update position of `player` and `babycrib` and check there is no collision between these two when `if(!player.overlaps(babycrib)){ }`

Comment: I already did sir @AbhishekAryan and still cant' collide with the babycrib.

Comment: how you update position of `player` and `babycrib`, please add that code

Comment: In my update method  `player.setPosition(getX(), getY());` , 
      `babycrib.setPosition(getX(), getY());`

Comment: what is `getX()` and `getY()` ?

Comment: How can I resolve  it sir in update?  When I used `if(!player.overlaps(babycrib)){  Gdx.app.log("babycrib overlaps", "yes"); }` It didn't overlap

Comment: `update()` is your method, not a part of LibGDX API, so I don't have idea for your update. It's better to post all your class code that having `update()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `player.contains(babycrib)` for regular collision detection. You could also use `Intersector` for this but this also calculates the area of overlap occurring.

```
if (Intersector.intersectRectangles(player, babycrib, intersection))
{
  //player and babycrib are intersecting...
  if (intersection.contains(babyRoom))
  {
    //Collision happened in baby room.
  }
}
```

Comment: I will try this Sir @Madmenyo :)

Comment: Good day Sir @Madmenyo I try your codes it works but how can I intersect  the both side of the rectangle? the left and right of the babycrib.

Comment: You mean where it collides? Here is an answer to that:  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/29796/20075

Comment: Yes the player  intersect  in babycrib my app log message appear only when he reach the top side of babycrip..using this code my player stop when he reach the top side of babycrib.. `if (babycrib.contains(player))` {
            `Gdx.app.log("Collision happened in baby crib ", "yes"); ` ,
            
          `  if (player.y > 4000) player.y = 4000;
        } `

Answer (score 1):

Your code is somehow messy, may be because you're new for this Framework so I can't say exactly what's going wrong.

But at the point of **collision detection**, It's seems that you're only updating position of `player` rectangle that having zero width and height. Also not changing position of `babycrib` rectangle that having zero size too.

---

You're using :

`babycrib` `Rectangle`   <-----FOR------->  `sprite_baby` `Sprite` 
`player` `Rectangle`  <-----FOR----->  `catsprite` `Sprite`

Don't create new `Rectangle` for `Sprite`, `Sprite` having own `bounds` data member of type `Rectangle` so use bounds instead of new Rectangle.

Whenever you want to access `sprite_baby` rectangle use `sprite_baby.getBoundingRectangle()` and when you want to `catsprite`'s rectangle use `catsprite.getBoundingRectangle()`.

If you don't want to change more in your code, Keep reference of `Sprite`'s rectangle to your `Rectangle` variable like,

```
sprite_baby = new Sprite(baby);
babycrib = sprite_baby.getBoundingRectangle();
```

And

```
catsprite = new Sprite(cat);
player = catsprite.getBoundingRectangle();
```

Comment: Thank you Sir when I try `catsprite = new Sprite(cat);`
`player = catsprite.getBoundingRectangle();` My player is not displaying on my screen.

Comment: Print position of player on console, check is it on screen or not. You're also changing position of camera so make sure player is in camera viewport.

Answer (score -1):

Set width and height of your rectangles, for example:

```
player = new Rectangle();
player.setWidth( catsprite.getWidth() );    
player.setHeight( catsprite.getHeight() );

babycrib = new Rectangle();
babycrib.setWidth( babysprite.getWidth() );
babycrib.setHeight( babysprite.getHeight() );
```